# Simple land classification (urban, suburban, rural) using polygons in MapInfo?

Tags: polygon, mapinfo, land-classification

I have a large number of polygons which I need to classify as either rural, suburban or urban. These polygons represent wireless coverage for a cellular network. What I would like to achieve is a breakdown for each of these polygons as to how much rural, suburban and urban coverage they provide e.g polygon1 Rural: 74%, Urban: 0%, Suburban: 26%

Currently my polygons are in MapInfo tab files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have polygons defining the rural, suburban and urban areas? If so this should be fairly straightforward with a few steps

- add three float fields to your existing coverage table to hold the overlap percentage for rural, suburban and urban areas
- if you haven't got one already, add a unique ID column to your `Coverage` table and populate it (with `RowID` for example)
- using sql, select your rural, suburban and urban areas into individual query results tables e.g. 
  `SELECT * FROM LandClassification WHERE Class = "Rural" INTO RuralArea`
- for each land class, use another SQL statement to calculate the overlap percentage e.g. 
  `SELECT Coverage.ID, Sum(ProportionOverlap(Coverage.obj, RuralArea.obj)) "PercentRural" 
  FROM Coverage, RuralArea 
  WHERE Coverage.obj INTERSECTS RuralArea.obj 
  GROUP BY Coverage.ID 
  INTO RuralCoverage`
- Once you have your three percentage coverage results tables you can use these to update the fields we created in the `Coverage` table in step 1 by joining them on the `ID` field

The overlap percentage will be in decimal format so if you want to show this as a percentage you will need to multiply the values by 100 when you update the `Coverage` table in the last step.